# iOS animating UILabel expand

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-animation

I have a UILabel that's initiated with 3 lines of text:

```
locationDescription = [[UILabel alloc]init];
locationDescription.numberOfLines = 3;
[locationDescription setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self addSubview:locationDescription];
```

I then have a button that expands the label:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{locationDescription.numberOfLines = 0;}
     ];
}
```

The desired behavior for the label is to have each extra line reveal itself one at a time. The label expands fine, but the transition isn't animated and all the lines just show up at once.

What am I missing?

Comment: You set the number of lines outside the animation body, then inside it.  Is that a typo here?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Code edited.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but still: `-init` is not the designated initializer for UILabel -- use `-initWithFrame:` instead.

Comment: @Caleb `-init` for `UIView` is equivalent to `initWithFrame:CGRectZero`, so it is totally fine to call `-init`. Only when overriding this becomes important.

Comment: @coverback Good to know -- I think this is the second time I'm learning that. ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can animate number of lines.  It changes the intrinsicSize of the `UILabel`.  You need to call layoutIfNeeded inside your animation block on the view containing the UILabel.  Here I attach a tap gesture to the table to toggle it between having 0 (as many as you want) lines and 1 line.

```
 func tapLabel(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
 {
    if let label = tapGesture.view as? UILabel {
      label.numberOfLines = label.numberOfLines == 0 ? 1 : 0
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        label.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: This works. One gotcha: in my experience, label.numberOfLines must begin at 0.

Comment: with "Content Mode" under "View" to "top" it will smoothly reveal the hidden lines...

Comment: @AxelZehden it is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @AxelZehden : Respect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, is it possible to make the animation in a way that the label simply "expands" downwards? The one in your answer looks like the text would scroll in from top of the label's bounds.

Answer (score 3):

UIView animateWithDuration's block object contains the changes to commit to the views. This is where you programmatically change any animatable properties of the views in your view hierarchy. But the property that you have specified, numberOfLines, is not animatable property.

The following properties of the UIView class which is parent class of UILabel are animatable:

```
 @property frame
 @property bounds
 @property center
 @property transform
 @property alpha
 @property backgroundColor
 @property contentStretch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't animate number of lines, you should animate size, and set number of lines to be 0 from the very start.

I am not adding height calculation code as it would hide the real animation here.

```
self.locationDescription = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.locationDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
[locationDescription setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

// Say, it starts with 50. In your real code, height should be calculated
// to fit the size you want, rounded to lines
NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"locationDescription": self.locationDescription};
[self.locationDescription addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[locationDescription(50)]"
                                         options:0 metrics:nil
                                           views:viewsDict];
```

Then in the action, do

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
    // Assuming there is only one constraint. If not, assign it to another property
    // I put 500, but, again, real size rounded to line height should be here
    self.locationDescription.constraints[0].constant = 500;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        // Layouting superview, as its frame can be updated because of a new size
        [self.locationDescription.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Also, you should assign `locationDescription` to a property and access it with `self.` in front.

Comment: I actually started off doing this, but the layoutIfNeeded seemed to redraw the text as well, so when the object animated, both the text and the bounding box were moving around.

Comment: @sheepgobeep One option is to use `TTTAttributedLabel`, which has a vertical alignment support, in that case text would stay on the same spot, revealing new lines.