# UILabel: multiple lines of text animation fade line by line

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel

for example:

```
label.text = @"I \n love \n stackoverflow ";
```

how to show those three lines just like first animation fade show "I" , then after animation during time animation fade show "love" finally after animation during time animation fade show "stackoverflow"?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958175/ios-animating-uilabel-expand

Comment: @Glenn thanks but it's not what i want. i want three lines of text showing with animations line by line just like UITableView reload cells with animation fede.

Comment: Did you try to use 3 UILabel and animate label one by one @J.Hoff?

Comment: @trungduc just for this effect, i can user three labels like you said and i can also use UITableView to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function for your request. Make sure your label have dynamic height, `numberOfLines` = 0 and try it ;)

```
- (void)animateLabel:(UILabel*)label withString:(NSString*)string duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  NSUInteger length = [string length];
  NSUInteger paraStart = 0, paraEnd = 0, contentsEnd = 0;
  NSMutableArray *displayedStringArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSRange currentRange;

  while (paraEnd < length) {
    [string getParagraphStart:&paraStart end:&paraEnd
              contentsEnd:&contentsEnd forRange:NSMakeRange(paraEnd, 0)];
    currentRange = NSMakeRange(0, contentsEnd);
    [displayedStringArray addObject:[string substringWithRange:currentRange]];
  }


  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  animation.duration = duration;
  animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
  animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

  __block void (^animationBlock) (int lineNumber);
  __block void (^weakAnimationBlock) (int lineNumber);
  animationBlock = ^void(int lineNumber){
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(duration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [label.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
      label.text = displayedStringArray[lineNumber];

      weakAnimationBlock = animationBlock;
      __block int nextLine = lineNumber + 1;

      if (nextLine < displayedStringArray.count) {
        weakAnimationBlock(nextLine);
      }
    });
  };

  animationBlock(0);
}
```

Simply call

`[YOUR_CLASS animateLabel:label withString:@"I\nLove\nStackOverFlow" duration:YOUR_DURATION];]`