# Issue in increase height of cell on Read more UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

Perhaps my question repeats itself. But no one of the answers not helped mea.

Now I have **UITableViewController** with **static cells** and different rowHeight in each **static cells**.

And I have **UIButton** who should help me to reveal the full text in my **UILabel**.

- The first row has implement **collectionView** and height == 490.0
- The second row has text in **UILabel** that I want to show in full text when I click on **UIButton** and height on default 150.0, but me need more height if text will have a lot of text
- The third row has implement **collectionView** and height == 150.0
- The fourth row has implement **collectionView** and height == 150.0
- The fifth row has **UILabel** and height == 50.0

And my screenShot what I'm talking about.

And my code:

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var conveniencesCollectionView: UICollectionView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var equipmentAndOtherCollectionView: UICollectionView! 

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var readMoreButton: UIButton!

    var hall: Halls?

    let eq = ["Без проходной", "Циклорама", "Дневной свет", "Условия для семинаров", "Трехфазная нагрузка", "Генераторный свет", "Моноблоки", "Системы крепления"]
    let con = ["Wi-Fi", "Платная парковка", "Кофе-машина", "Душ", "Организация мероприятий"] // [""]

    var readMore: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        descriptionLabel.text = hall.description
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0: return 1
        case 1: return 1
        case 2: if eq.isEmpty || eq == [""] { return 0 } else { return 1 }
        case 3: if con.isEmpty || con == [""] { return 0 } else { return 1 } 
        default: return 1
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    @IBAction func readMoreButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        readMore = true
        readMoreButton.isHidden = true
        //... code for reveal text
    }
}
```

**hall.description** has text `Пространство рассчитано на различные виды съёмок. Также возможно проведение различных мастер-классов, семинаров, встреч и мероприятий. Профессиональное оборудование Profoto D1 500 Air (4 источника) и крепкими стойками Manfrotto. Великолепная акустика. Крепкая белоснежная циклорама с регулируемым подогревом пола.2 больших окна, дающие великолепный дневной жесткий и мягкий свет (солнечная сторона). Аудиосистема с USB и AUX. Уникальные декорации в LOFT стиле. Бесплатное гримерное место перед съемкой.Бесплатный wi-fi.`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Дмитрий Деникаев.

**I have found Solution.** You can check my working demo project [here.](https://github.com/RishilPatel94/FlexibleCell.git).

1) You need to set `UILabel` property `setNumberOfLines = 0`.

[image]

2) Create two `@IBOutlet` constraint for view increase and decrease and set its `priority`. ex. `priority = 750` and `priority = 250`(**vice versa**).

- first constrain for label fix hight and its priority in story board is 750.

  [image]
- second constrain for label bottom to its superview and its priority in story board is 250.

  [image]

**look into following code **

In **ViewTableViewCell.swift**

```
  import UIKit

class ViewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var fixedHeightCon : NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var graterHeightCon : NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnMore: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

in **ViewController.swift**

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  arrData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : ViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewTableViewCell
        cell.btnMore.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.lblText.text  = arrData[indexPath.row]
        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    var arrData = ["This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.This is long description.","This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123.This is long description123."]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tblView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 77
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func changelabelHeight(sender:UIButton){
        let indexpath = NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = self.tblView!.cellForRow(at: indexpath as IndexPath) as? ViewTableViewCell

        if(cell!.fixedHeightCon.priority == UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)){
            cell!.btnMore.setTitle("Show Less", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell!.fixedHeightCon.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)
            cell!.graterHeightCon.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)



        }else{
            cell!.btnMore.setTitle("Read More", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell!.fixedHeightCon.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
            cell!.graterHeightCon.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)

        }
        tblView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

I hope this answer helpful to you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have this installed, I do not understand how to configure the deployment of the cell

Comment: It will work with static cell? Because my tableView have static cell

Comment: Yes it's working in both static cell and dynamic cell. just you have to set your conditions

Comment: still let me know if you have any issue.Thanks

Comment: Thanks, great solution! It helped me.

Comment: If it is helpful then you can accept and upvote it so it can helpful in other users and que and ans will come in priority.   Thanks!  happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would set the `.amountOfLines` property on your `UILabel` to something like 5, that would truncate the string automatically to fit 5 lines. Then when the user taps the Read More button, change it to 0 to allow the `UILabel` to have infinite lines to show the entire text. If you remove the height limit you put on the cell and have auto layout set up correctly, it would scale automatically.

Additionally, if you want to have the expanding of the UILabel animated, you can find that solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34284563/5544222